# iOS - not able to add http header of URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, url, request, wkwebview

I am trying to add http header to URLRequest, which I am loading in WKWebView.

I tried this code:

```
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!)
    urlRequest.addValue("value", forHTTPHeaderField: "key")
    self.viewerWebKit.load(urlRequest)
```

and also this:

```
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!)
    urlRequest.setValue("value", forHTTPHeaderField: "key")
    self.viewerWebKit.load(urlRequest)
```

But when I am printing http headers with this code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    let headers = (navigationResponse.response as! HTTPURLResponse).allHeaderFields
    for (key,value) in headers {
        print("key \(key) value \(value)")
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

nothing is added or set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're checking the response headers, they don't have to be the same as the response headers. So if you want to check the headers you set, I suggest using a proxy tool like Charles, it's quite easy to use it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Will try it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
  decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, 
  decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

Use this delegate function. You can find headers of request in navigationAction.request.

Answer (score 1):

**URLRequest** immutable so if you want to add header in that request you need to make it mutable.use this extension to add header.

```
extension URLRequest {

internal mutating func addHeaders() {

        let mutableRequest = ((self as NSURLRequest).mutableCopy() as? NSMutableURLRequest)!


            mutableRequest.setValue("your header", forHTTPHeaderField: "key")
            self = mutableRequest as URLRequest

        }
    }

}
```

Use where you want to set Header:

```
request.addHeaders()
```

Comment: I didn't know that. Where am I supposed to add that extension? Which file?

Comment: in same file you can add. at the end of file add this  code.

Comment: It gives me error: "Declaration is only valid at file scope"

Comment: Ah I see. It must me outside of the class.